# Error when trying to use Button in react-native

Tags: react-native

When making a simple react-native program I cannot get the `<Button>`  component to work. The error I always get after `react-native run-android` is

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   com.facebook.react.uimanager.AccessibilityDelegateUtil$AccessibilityRole

When I omit the button, everything works fine, and I can click the Text just fine.

code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';



type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

        <Button onPress={()=>console.log('hi')} title="go"/>
        <Text onPress={()=>console.log('hi')}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>

      </View>
        );
      }
 }
```

some dependencies :

```
  "dependencies": {
 maar eens alles goed staat hoop ik gewoon dat de miserie gedaan is, cf   "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

I've just tested your code on version `0.55`. It was perfectly correct and worked fine.
I'm likely to have error with your `react-native` version.

init lower version

```
react-native init --version="react-native@0.55.0" YOUR_APP_NAME
```

before that try this also

```
<Button
    onPress={() => alert('hi')}
    title="Press Me"
 >
   Press Me
</Button>
```

Comment: +1 , since this works, and you took time to help out, leaving it as unaccepted since I would like to get the latest version to work. Tx!

Comment: It works. But strange that such a simple thing as Button does not work on 0.57.3 !??

Answer (score 2):

A new version of react-native `0.57.4` is now out. Please update your react native version. I tested with the new version and  just working fine now.

Hope it works for you too! :)

Comment: i am already on latest 0.60.4 but it is giving me this error " Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-button'. 'e:/ReactNative/apisauce/node_modules/react-native-button/Button.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. " don't know why i have installed the react-native-button but still doesn't work