# How do I fix this React Native error:"java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.uimanager"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, error-handling, compiler-errors, react-redux

I used the following segments of code to create a new button but I got the "**java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.uimanager.AccessibilityDelegateUtil$AccessibilityRole**" error. I did some digging and it seemed as though it was an error resulting from React Native 0.57.3 was unstable, so I downgraded to 0.57.1 as suggested from a multitude of  forum posts. The error persisted however, so if you could look through my code and give me suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

**My code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

import FetchLocation from './components/FetchLocation';

export default class App extends React.Component{
  getUserLocationHandler = () => {

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FetchLocation onGetLocation={this.getUserLocationHandler} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

**Also my code:**

```
  import React from 'react';
    import { Button } from 'react-native';

    const fetchLocation = props => {
              return (
            <Button title="Get Location" onPress={props.onGetLocation}/>
              );
    };

    export default fetchLocation;
```

**Here's an image of the error:** 
[image: Error:]

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: It doesn't say explicitly but I edited a picture of the error for your convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is 0.57 while [Error when trying to use Button in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782396/error-when-trying-to-use-button-in-react-native) says it works in 0.55 version. Better give it a try.

**Edit**

I tried it myself and found this solution. Downgrade react-native to 57.2 and make sure to downgrade other dependencies as below,

```
    "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  }
```

then try deleting node_modules and doing `npm install & npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: So am I haha. Thanks again.

Comment: Or upgrade to 0.57.5